# New line after the :: for member function definitions in C++

Tags: c++, clang-format

I use clang-format and I want my member function definitions to be formatted in a new line like this:

```cpp
void MyClass::
configure(const std::string& p) {
    // code
}
```

With my current clang format definition

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
ColumnLimit: 120
AccessModifierOffset: -4
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: true
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: All
```

I am able to format to the following style, which is not what I am after

```cpp
void 
MyClass::configure(const std::string& p) {
    // code
}
```

My current clang-format version is:

```
$ clang-format --version
clang-format version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
```

Is the thing I'm asking about even possible with clang-format or should I use some other formatter?

Comment: I dont know if this is possible, but it would not surprising for me if this would not be possible, because that formating is very unusual (I have never seen this before)